# Dot net core Serilog If there any way not to show errors in Console and shows only information and warnings

Tags: .net-core, serilog

Console application project .. In my code I want to hide errors from console, How Can I do that without hide information and warnings

```
return logger.MinimumLevel.Verbose()
             .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Verbose)
             .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Serilog.Filters.Matching.FromSource<Transformer>())
             .Enrich.FromLogContext()
             .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Information)
             .WriteTo.Async(config => config.File(Path.Combine(logsPath, runId + "-logFileName.log"),
              rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
             fileSizeLimitBytes: 314572800));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return logger.MinimumLevel.Verbose()
         .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Verbose)
         .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Serilog.Filters.Matching.FromSource<Transformer>())
         .Enrich.FromLogContext()
         .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
             .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(le => le.Level == LogEventLevel.Information || le.Level == LogEventLevel.Warning)
             .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Information))
         .WriteTo.Async(config =>
             config.File(
                 Path.Combine(logsPath, runId + "-logFileName.log"),
                 rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                 fileSizeLimitBytes: 314572800));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works fine but only the information shows  in the console, I added (||) warnings and it works fine, both of information and warnings show now

.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(le => le.Level == LogEventLevel.Information || le.Level == LogEventLevel.Warning)